# Check user has like facebook fanpage with facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

im new for facebook application development !
So i have new project with use facebook sdk to show facebook plugin fanpage like box if use are connect and not like this fanpage

My code html.index

```
<html>
      <body>
             <div id="fb-root"></div>
             <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like>
      </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : appId,
  xfbml      : false, //boot to load speed
  cookie     : true,
  status     : true,
  version    : appVersion
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {


    if (response.status == 'connected') {
          var UserId = response.authResponse.userID; //get user id
          FB.api('/me/likes/'+fanpageId, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data[0]) {
               //user has liked
            } else {
                FB.XFBML.parse(); //parse show plugin
            }
        });

    } else {
       //user not login
    }
});

};

//render facebook SDK
   (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/" + appLanguage +               "/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

but the plugin alway show without

i need when user connect and does not like this page , the plugin show !

One question ! why respone UserId not same with my profile Id ?

Comment: You need to make the user login and grant you user_likes permission

Comment: any way without login ! thanks !!

Comment: That would be a security problem.

Comment: If this is a page tab app you will get a liked property in the signed request. Otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the backend. I hear it is convenient to do using PHP but I am a Java guy, so I will tell you how I did that using Java. I have a servlet, which I call FanGateServlet. What it does is get the signed_request which is sent my Facebook when you access the application, decoding it to figure out whether the user has liked the page or not. **Use doPost method of the servlet**.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String signedReq = request.getParameter("signed_request");

            if (signedReq == null) {
                logger.warn("ERROR: Unable to retrieve signed_request parameter");
                response.sendRedirect(appDomain+"/default.html");
            } else {
                Base64 base64 = new Base64();

                // split request into signature and data
                String[] signedRequest = signedReq.split("\\.", 2);

                // parse signature
    //          String sig = new String(base64.decode(signedRequest[0].getBytes("UTF-8")));

                // parse data and convert to json object
                String data = new String(base64.decode(signedRequest[1].getBytes("UTF-8")));

                // check whether the user has 'liked' the page
                boolean isLikedPage = data.contains("\"page\":{\"id\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"liked\":true");

                if (isLikedPage) {
                    response.sendRedirect(appDomain+"/home.html");
                }else{
                    response.sendRedirect(appDomain+"/like-page.html");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - this is your page id.
home.html - the page you show to the fans who have liked your page. 
like-page.html - the page you show to the users who have not yet liked your page.

For this to work, you should have [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) jar in your application server. (Not Project lib folder)

One more important thing, in Facebook Developer settings, under **Page Tab** settings, Page Tab Url should be the url to your servlet pattern.

```
http://appDomain/fangate.do
```

In web.xml of course, you should map fangate.do mapping to your FanGateServlet.java

Not only you can read the signed_request to see whether the user has liked your page (without getting user permission in javascript sdk), in my case I wanted to send parameters too. You can do this using app_data. Let me know if any more thing should be more explained. :)